# Ruby on Rails if/else condition not working

Tags: ruby, if-statement, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails application view where I want to display one of two partials depending on the ENV variable setting. For some reason, the condition is always evaluated to false so the `campaign_active` partial is displayed. I've changed the ENV to `true` and tried switching the rendering statements around and found that only the statement after `else` gets executed. What am I missing?

Here's the view:

```
<% if Rails.application.config.ended %>
  <%= render "users/campaign_ended" %>
<% else %>
  <%= render "users/campaign_active" %>
<% end %>
```

Here's the `application.rb` setting:

```
config.ended = ENV['CAMPAIGN_ENDED'].to_s == 'true'
```

Here's the `.ENV` file:

```
CAMPAIGN_ENDED=true
```

The campaign setting in ENV is set to true so I expect the condition in my view to be true and render the campaign_ended partial. But instead, it renders the campaign_active partial. Now if I switch the statements around and put `campaign active` ahead of campaign ended, then the `campaign ended` partial renders.

Comment: Did you ever check what `ENV['CAMPAIGN_ENDED']` actually returns at that point in time in the code? How do you handle reading `.ENV` in your code, do you use a gem or something written on your own?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the dotenv-rails gem grouped under development & test. all of my other settings in my ENV file are working fine. I should add that I'm using the Suspenders template (https://github.com/thoughtbot/suspenders) 
How can I check what ```ENV['CAMPAIGN_ENDED']``` returns?

Comment: The dotenv-rails gem expect the files name to be downcase (`.env`). Can you please rename your file and check again? Did you include the code require to load the env file into your `config/application.rb`? And is your `config.ended =` code after that `Dotenv::Railtie.load` call? To check the value of `ENV['CAMPAIGN_ENDED']` You can simply log its value to the Rails log and that search for that entry: `Rails.logger.debug("ENV['CAMPAIGN_ENDED'] => #{ENV['CAMPAIGN_ENDED'].inspect}")` It show up early after restarting the server.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was missing the ```Dotenv::Railtie.load``` code required to load the env file. I thought it would have been all set up during the template configuration because when I ran the server for the first time, everything worked as if all the env configs were loading fine. 

Just in case anyone else experiences this issue in future, you need to reset the server after you modify your .ENV file otherwise you won't see the results.

Thanks again @spickermann

Comment: Using environment variables to change run-time behaviour is pretty heavy-handed. You'll need to reboot your Rails process(es) to effect this change. It's often better to have a cut-off date where you can flip over from one to another, like `if (Campaign.ended?)` where that's a module that implements the logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please double check that you are loading your `.env` file in the `config/application.rb` with

```
Dotenv::Railtie.load
```

before you actually use the environment variable in this line

```
config.ended = ENV['CAMPAIGN_ENDED'].to_s == 'true'
```

Remember that you need to restart the Rails application after changing the `.env` file.